# Como puedo hacer un menu flotante como en Wix

Tags: menú, responsive

Tengo este tipo de menu:

```
 <div class="call">

    <a href="#"><p class="call-items" title="About">Hola</p></a>
    <a href="#"><p class="call-items" title="Home">Como</p></a>
    <a href="#"><p class="call-items" title="Something">Es</p></a>
    <a href="#"><p class="call-items" title="ANother">Enlace 1</p></a>
    <a href="#"><p class="call-items" title="Some">Enlace 2</p></a>
    <a href="#"><p class="call-items" title="Done"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></p></a>
    <p class="call-menu" title="Menu"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></p>

</div>
```

quisiera que fuera como el de WIX que tiene iconos y que al deplegar aparecen sub menus como en la imagen

[image: Menu Wix]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, 
también es muy importante que leas [Ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer submenús puedes meter listas (ul) dentro de items de listas (li), hacer que no esten desplegadas (display:none) y cuando pases el puntero en un item (li:hover) que se desplegue la lista anidada (ul{display:inline-block;}), aquí tienes un ejemplo de lo que te he dicho, espero que te sirva como base para conseguir lo que quieres.

```css
header {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom:2em;
}
header ul {
  list-style: none;
}
header > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  width:25%;
}
header > ul > li a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
header > ul li:hover > ul {
  display: inline-block;
}
header > ul li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #585858;
}
header ul li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  width: 15%;
}
header ul li ul li {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <ul>
    <li><a>A</a>
      <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>4</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>B</a>
      <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>C</a>
      <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Comment: y como puedo alinear el menu a la izquierda de manera fija o flotante